# How much tissue is required to do RNA-seq analysis on a single organism?

Tags: transcription, rna-sequencing

How much tissue would be required to do RNA-seq analysis on a single organism? 
More specifically, if a person wanted an RNA-seq analysis of expression for a single organ, how much tissue would they need to donate?

Comment: Depends on a lot of parameters? Can you add some more details?

Answer (score 3):

Our DNA core wants 1.5 ug of RNA.  I find that I can obtain that amount from a standard Trizol prep from about 1 mg of Arabidopsis floral tissue.  I usually double or triple what I harvest to account for random variation in yield.

Comment: Any sources to add? +1 for this contribution and welcome 2 Bio

Comment: ThermoFisher has [literally everything in tabular format](https://www.thermofisher.com/us/en/home/references/ambion-tech-support/rna-isolation/general-articles/rna-yields-from-tissues-and-cells.html). As a side note I'd also peg an A260/A280 > 1.8 as equally important as yield for best results.

Answer (score 1):

http://healthcare.utah.edu/huntsmancancerinstitute/research/shared-resources/center-managed/high-throughput-genomics-site/services/illumina-sequencing/rna-sequencing.php

> The Illumina TruSeq RNA Sample Prep Kit v2 with oligo(dT) selection
>   recommends an input of 100 to 1000 ng of total RNA in a volume of 30
>   ul for library construction.
>
> The Epicentre TotalScript RNA-Seq Kit (Epicentre cat# TSRNA1296) is
>   designed for an input of 1-5 ng of total RNA in a volume of 12 ul to a
>   RNA sequencing library.

Whether you will get a complete picture of a whole organ from such a small slice is an entirely different question.  The brain has different regions, with different gene expression.